# Spring @Transactional anotation not working in a for loop with using try catch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

My question is given below. **Pseudocode Code is given below**:

```java
public Object rollBackTestMainMethod(List<Object> list) {

  List<Object> responseList = new ArrayList<>();

  for(Object item:list){

    try{    
      Boolean isOperationSuccess = rollBackTestSubMethod(item);
      if (isOperationSuccess==null || !isOperationSuccess){
        item.addError("Operation failed");
        item.addSuccess(false);
      } else {
        item.addError(null);
        item.addSuccess(true);
      }

    } catch(Exception exception) {
      item.addError(exception.getMessage());
      item.addSuccess(false);
    }

    responseList.add(item);
  }

  return responseList;
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class, SQLException.class})
private Boolean rollBackTestSubMethod(Object listItem){

  Long value1=save(listItem.getValue1());
  if(value1==null){
    throw new Exception("Error during save 1");
  }

  Long value2=save(listItem.getValue2());
  if(value2==null){
    throw new Exception("Error during save 2");
  }
  Long value3=save(listItem.getValue3());
  if(value3==null){
    throw new Exception("Error during save 3");
  }

  return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

**What I am doing here:**

1. Iterate a list in `rollBackTestMainMethod()`. Sending one list item in `rollBackTestSubMethod()` and performing a 3 save operation.
2. If all save complete then returning true response, otherwise throwing an exception.
3. In `rollBackTestMainMethod()`, after getting response or exception, it is adding error or successful value on each item.
4. It is adding this item in new list named `responseList`. After all operations it is sending this back as response.

**My questions:**

1. After throwing from `rollBackTestSubMethod()` it will not be rolled back because it is calling from a try catch block.
2. If I want to forcefully roll back via `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();` then it will be rolled back all item for any throw/exception.
3. **Here I want rollback only for throw item not all item.**
4. This method's are in a spring bean
5. I am saving data into my relational database via **spring data jpa**

**My imports:**

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport;
```

Comment: `rollbackFor = {Exception.class, SQLException.class}` is extraneous. Method doesn't `throws SQLException` or any other checked exceptions, and `@Transactional` defaults to rollback on `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Thanks sir for your comment. I am just added sudo code. Please ignore SqlException :)

Comment: *"Sudo code"*? Did you mean [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)?

Comment: ohh sorry, its pseudocode

Comment: Sudo code is actually better than pseudocode. Back yourself @Andreas

Answer (score 14):

It's because you're invoking `@Transactional` method from within same bean.

`@Transactional` only works on methods invoked on proxies created by spring. It means, that when you create a `@Service` or other bean, method called from the outside will be transactional. If invoked from within bean, nothing will happen, as it doesn't pass through proxy object.

The easiest solution would be to move the method to another `@Service` or bean. If you really want to keep it within same component, then you need to invoke it, so that it gets wrapped in proxy by spring AOP. You can do this like that:

```
private YourClass self;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@PostConstruct
public void postContruct(){
    self = applicationContext.getBean(YourClass.class);
}
```

Then invoking method on `self` would result in opening a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
I am saving data into my database via spring data JPA. Can you please elaborate your answer clearly. Also how can i achieve my goal, "I want rollback only for throwed item not all item"

Comment: What is unclear in my explanation?:) It's the idea of transaction - it's rolled back as one, atomic operation...

Comment: Also if you find this answer helpful, consider upvoting / marking as correct to help others with same problem:)

Comment: I would really like to keep these things in one service, but to me the `self` proposal seems like something that should be omitted. Is it a fine approach or just a last resort thing?

Comment: @devaga you're right about that, it's cleaner to keep those things in separate services than self-injection. But it's possible and the trick comes in handy in rare cases

Answer (score 0):

Marking a non-public method @Transactional is both useless and misleading because Spring doesn't "see" non-public methods, and so makes no provision for their proper invocation. Nor does Spring make provision for the methods invoked by the method it called.

Therefore marking a private method, for instance, @Transactional can only result in a runtime error or exception if the method is actually written to be @Transactional.